# Why does PAP authentication not work in Packet tracer 7.2?

Tags: packet-tracer, ppp

**Note** : Platform = Packet Tracer 7.2.1 for Linux 64 bit on Fedora 29.

[image: Topology]

I configured two serial interfaces in packet tracer v7.2 for PAP authentication. While one of them has the status `up/up`, the other, PAP server has the status `up/down`:

```
R1#sh ip int br
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Serial0/3/0            10.1.1.1        YES manual up                    down 
Serial0/3/1            unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down


R2(config-if)#do sh ip int br
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
GigabitEthernet0/0     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
GigabitEthernet0/1     unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Serial0/3/0            10.1.1.2        YES manual up                    up 
Serial0/3/1            unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

I recreated the same network and config in GNS3 (IOU img) and it works, and I can ping each router from the other. This however, doesn't work in PT7.2. Why is this? Is it a bug in PT or did I misconfigure it?

P.S. Here's the interface status in PT:

```
R1#sh int s0/3/0
Serial0/3/0 is up, line protocol is down (disabled)
  Hardware is HD64570
  Internet address is 10.1.1.1/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1544 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation PPP, loopback not set, keepalive set (10 sec)
  LCP Closed
  Closed: LEXCP, BRIDGECP, IPCP, CCP, CDPCP, LLC2, BACP
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0 (size/max/drops); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: weighted fair
  Output queue: 0/1000/64/0 (size/max total/threshold/drops)
     Conversations  0/0/256 (active/max active/max total)
     Reserved Conversations 0/0 (allocated/max allocated)
     Available Bandwidth 1158 kilobits/sec
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions
     DCD=up  DSR=up  DTR=up  RTS=up  CTS=up

R2(config-if)#do sh int s0/3/0
Serial0/3/0 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is HD64570
  Internet address is 10.1.1.2/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1544 Kbit, DLY 20000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation PPP, loopback not set, keepalive set (10 sec)
  LCP Open
  Open: IPCP, CDPCP
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0 (size/max/drops); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: weighted fair
  Output queue: 0/1000/64/0 (size/max total/threshold/drops)
     Conversations  0/0/256 (active/max active/max total)
     Reserved Conversations 0/0 (allocated/max allocated)
     Available Bandwidth 1158 kilobits/sec
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     5 packets output, 640 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 2 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions
     DCD=up  DSR=up  DTR=up  RTS=up  CTS=up
```

---

Here's my config on R1:

```
R1#sh run 
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 840 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
username papuser password 0 pappass
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524RG40-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.252
 encapsulation ppp
 ppp authentication pap
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Here's the R2 config:

```
R2(config-if)#do sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 808 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO2901/K9 sn FTX1524751T-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/3/0
 ip address 10.1.1.2 255.255.255.252
 encapsulation ppp
 ppp pap sent-username papuser password 0 pappass
!
interface Serial0/3/1
 no ip address
 clock rate 2000000
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

---

### Update:

Here are the controller details for both:

R1:

```
R1#sh controller s0/3/0
Interface Serial0/3/0
Hardware is PowerQUICC MPC860
DCE V.35, clock rate 2000000
idb at 0x81081AC4, driver data structure at 0x81084AC0
SCC Registers:
General [GSMR]=0x2:0x00000000, Protocol-specific [PSMR]=0x8
Events [SCCE]=0x0000, Mask [SCCM]=0x0000, Status [SCCS]=0x00
Transmit on Demand [TODR]=0x0, Data Sync [DSR]=0x7E7E
Interrupt Registers:
Config [CICR]=0x00367F80, Pending [CIPR]=0x0000C000
Mask   [CIMR]=0x00200000, In-srv  [CISR]=0x00000000
Command register [CR]=0x580
Port A [PADIR]=0x1030, [PAPAR]=0xFFFF
       [PAODR]=0x0010, [PADAT]=0xCBFF
Port B [PBDIR]=0x09C0F, [PBPAR]=0x0800E
       [PBODR]=0x00000, [PBDAT]=0x3FFFD
Port C [PCDIR]=0x00C, [PCPAR]=0x200
       [PCSO]=0xC20,  [PCDAT]=0xDF2, [PCINT]=0x00F
Receive Ring
        rmd(68012830): status 9000 length 60C address 3B6DAC4
        rmd(68012838): status B000 length 60C address 3B6D444
Transmit Ring
        tmd(680128B0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128B8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128C0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128C8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128D0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128D8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128E0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128E8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128F0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128F8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012900): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012908): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012910): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012918): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012920): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012928): status 2000 length 0 address 0

tx_limited=1(2)

SCC GENERAL PARAMETER RAM (at 0x68013C00)
Rx BD Base [RBASE]=0x2830, Fn Code [RFCR]=0x18
Tx BD Base [TBASE]=0x28B0, Fn Code [TFCR]=0x18
Max Rx Buff Len [MRBLR]=1548
Rx State [RSTATE]=0x0, BD Ptr [RBPTR]=0x2830
Tx State [TSTATE]=0x4000, BD Ptr [TBPTR]=0x28B0

SCC HDLC PARAMETER RAM (at 0x68013C38)
CRC Preset [C_PRES]=0xFFFF, Mask [C_MASK]=0xF0B8
Errors: CRC [CRCEC]=0, Aborts [ABTSC]=0, Discards [DISFC]=0
Nonmatch Addr Cntr [NMARC]=0
Retry Count [RETRC]=0
Max Frame Length [MFLR]=1608
Rx Int Threshold [RFTHR]=0, Frame Cnt [RFCNT]=0
User-defined Address 0000/0000/0000/0000
User-defined Address Mask 0x0000


buffer size 1524

PowerQUICC SCC specific errors:
0 input aborts on receiving flag sequence
0 throttles, 0 enables
0 overruns
0 transmitter underruns
0 transmitter CTS losts
0 aborted short frames
```

R2:

```
R2#sh con s0/3/0
Interface Serial0/3/0
Hardware is PowerQUICC MPC860
DTE V.35 TX and RX clocks detected
idb at 0x81081AC4, driver data structure at 0x81084AC0
SCC Registers:
General [GSMR]=0x2:0x00000000, Protocol-specific [PSMR]=0x8
Events [SCCE]=0x0000, Mask [SCCM]=0x0000, Status [SCCS]=0x00
Transmit on Demand [TODR]=0x0, Data Sync [DSR]=0x7E7E
Interrupt Registers:
Config [CICR]=0x00367F80, Pending [CIPR]=0x0000C000
Mask   [CIMR]=0x00200000, In-srv  [CISR]=0x00000000
Command register [CR]=0x580
Port A [PADIR]=0x1030, [PAPAR]=0xFFFF
       [PAODR]=0x0010, [PADAT]=0xCBFF
Port B [PBDIR]=0x09C0F, [PBPAR]=0x0800E
       [PBODR]=0x00000, [PBDAT]=0x3FFFD
Port C [PCDIR]=0x00C, [PCPAR]=0x200
       [PCSO]=0xC20,  [PCDAT]=0xDF2, [PCINT]=0x00F
Receive Ring
        rmd(68012830): status 9000 length 60C address 3B6DAC4
        rmd(68012838): status B000 length 60C address 3B6D444
Transmit Ring
        tmd(680128B0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128B8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128C0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128C8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128D0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128D8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128E0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128E8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128F0): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(680128F8): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012900): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012908): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012910): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012918): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012920): status 0 length 0 address 0
        tmd(68012928): status 2000 length 0 address 0

tx_limited=1(2)

SCC GENERAL PARAMETER RAM (at 0x68013C00)
Rx BD Base [RBASE]=0x2830, Fn Code [RFCR]=0x18
Tx BD Base [TBASE]=0x28B0, Fn Code [TFCR]=0x18
Max Rx Buff Len [MRBLR]=1548
Rx State [RSTATE]=0x0, BD Ptr [RBPTR]=0x2830
Tx State [TSTATE]=0x4000, BD Ptr [TBPTR]=0x28B0

SCC HDLC PARAMETER RAM (at 0x68013C38)
CRC Preset [C_PRES]=0xFFFF, Mask [C_MASK]=0xF0B8
Errors: CRC [CRCEC]=0, Aborts [ABTSC]=0, Discards [DISFC]=0
Nonmatch Addr Cntr [NMARC]=0
Retry Count [RETRC]=0
Max Frame Length [MFLR]=1608
Rx Int Threshold [RFTHR]=0, Frame Cnt [RFCNT]=0
User-defined Address 0000/0000/0000/0000
User-defined Address Mask 0x0000


buffer size 1524

PowerQUICC SCC specific errors:
0 input aborts on receiving flag sequence
0 throttles, 0 enables
0 overruns
0 transmitter underruns
0 transmitter CTS losts
0 aborted short frames
```